# C Named pipe CMD console app output 1st half disappears when scrollin

Tags: c, cmd, console

Hi I have this small issue where  I created a  Named pipe in C to execute commands in CMD on windows .

The problem is when the following command is executed  sc query state= all it returns 2000 results
If i open up a normal cmd window I can see all the results  but if I run it through my C named pipe console app  I get to see all the results too but  at a certain point  if I  scroll in the console app window  the first half of the results are no longer visible .

so out of 2836 results the first 1813 results get truncated in the c console app  window .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer you just have to adjust the console buffer size in command prompt to 3000 etc to cater for the additional data.